# Make entire row clickable - PHP approach

Tags: php, row

Hi programmers and web designers,
I am working on a small system for the company I work with and everything is almost done (thanks for this site and the help from other sites...) except for this function where I want the entire row of the table my php codes generated, for now I was only able to make my second column clickable. I already tried googling but I can't find a workable solution. FYI, I am a noob and just starting to learn php.... thanks in advance...

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))  
{ echo "<tr> class='tablerows' align=center onclick=\"window.location=http://active_jobs.php?job_ticket='".$info['job_ticket']."'\">
<td>".$info['date']."</td>; 
<td><a> href=somefile.php?job_ticket=".$info['job_ticket'].">".$info['job_ticket']."</td>
<td>".$info['invoice_no']."</td> <td>".$info['customer']."</td>
<td>".$info['job_type']."</td> <td>".$info['complete_date']."</td>
<td>".$info['complete_time']."</td>
<td>".$info['artist_operator_prepress']."</td>
<td>".$info['status_prepress']."</td>
<td>".$info['status_press']."</td>
<td>".$info['status_postpress']."</td> <td
width='300'>".$info['remarks']."</td>"; echo "</tr>"; 
} echo
"</table>";
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t make entire rows “clickable” using PHP. PHP is a server-side language; you generate HTML and spit it out.

If you wanted to make an entire table row clickable, you’d either have to wrap it in an `<a>` (invalid HTML), or use a client-side language such as JavaScript to apply an event listener, that listens for the `<tr>` being clicked and redirects to whatever URL you want.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me... It's working now!
Thanks Martin for mentioning the event listener thing. I used this:

    function DoNav(theUrl)
    {
    document.location.href = theUrl;
    }

and put the onclick inside the tr tag:

    echo "<tr onmouseover='ChangeColor(this, true);' 
    onmouseout='ChangeColor(this, false);'
    onclick='DoNav(\"somefile.php?job_ticket=".$info['job_ticket']."\");'>

Now I got the whole row clickable with proper link and hover-aid effect rows.

Thanks you so much guys...

Marco

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it’s the approach you used.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the generated html, you are closing the `<tr>` tag so the class and javascript are no longer part of it:

```
{ echo "<tr> class='tablerows' align=center onclick=\"window.location=http://active_jobs.php?job_ticket='".$info['job_ticket']."'\">
           ^ remove this and check the html again; it probably works now
```

You have the same mistake on the fourth line with the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

For those kind of live edit in table values with php, you can go for client side scripting language javascript & jquery with ajax..

For Reference :

[Live Edit table With Ajax](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html)

It's worthy...

Answer (score 0):

i am answering this question by assuming that you are aware of JQUERY.Written a sample code copy it into a file '.html' and run. make sure that you are connected to internet to let jquery api to load.Thanks.

ex:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('table tr').click( function () {
        alert('i am clicked');
        } );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>apple</td><td>boy</td><td>jjjj</td><td>dddd</td><td></td><td>1010</td><td>1019</td><td>06-Mar-13 21:47:34</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>strawberry</td><td>girl</td><td>jjjj</td><td>dddd</td><td></td><td>1010</td><td>1019</td><td>06-Mar-13 21:47:34</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>strawberry</td><td>girl</td><td>jjjj</td><td>dddd</td><td></td><td>1010</td><td>1019</td><td>06-Mar-13 21:47:34</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make a table row clickable.  It is very easy.  You just make invisible buttons inside each table sell.  Make them without borders and no colors.  Then, just handle the entire row as a clickable button.  You will need to do this for each TD in the row. Also, you have to have a unique id for each row so that the button can identify the row number.  Something loosely like this:

```
<td><button type='submit' name='click_row' value='" . $info["id"] . "' style='width: 100%; background: none; border: none; box-shadow: none;'>DATA FOR THIS TD</button></td>
```

Then, you need to process the buttons for the row.  ( Same button for each TD in the row. )  Something loosely like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["click_row"])) {
   $clicked_row = $_POST["click_row"];
   //  Handle what you want done with this row...
}
```

Works well for me!